# when we should use LRU cache? Is this a best solution?

Tags: android

I am totally new in this topic,i am confused when i should use LRU cache,can someone help?i want a scenario where we can use LRU and where it will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use an LRU cache when you have a set of objects that

1)You only need to use a subset of them at a time

2)The total memory use of the entire set is too big

3)You are capable of reloading the data for a specific object on command, but doing so for every item is time consuming.

4)There is locality of memory use-  an item that is recently uses is more likely to be used again soon.

The biggest example is a list of images.  Images are big, they take a lot of memory.  If you need 100 of them, you can't hold all those in Bitmaps-  you'll hit an OutOfMemoryException.  Instead you'd use an LRU cache to hold the last 10 or so that you worked with.  If you need to use one of those again, its already in the cache and quick to access.  If you need a new one, you can load it from disk (or from network).  This way you never use more than 10-11 bitmaps, and you never hit an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: I am not sure how do you propose to prevent OutOfMemoryException to be solved with a software cache? The cache is also in same address space as that of user of that cache. I guess you want to add that, the cached data is stored in some other application, and reading over descriptor like sockets is not as penalising as that of reading data from disk followed by serializing and reconstruction (which anyways you would do in both cases).

Comment: @ultimatecause  You don't need all of them at once.  So you cache up to N in case you need them again and use an LRU cache because it makes sense-  the ones you just saw are the ones you'll need again (say when scrolling).  The Bitmap objects are only ever held by the cache and the View, never by the model directly.  This allows you to keep them in memory for as long as possible, but gives you the flexibility to eject them when low memory occurs.  Its a fairly common technique.

Comment: I am not contending the temporal locality of reference. That is why we are talking about LRU in first place. I am only saying that you need to add/qualify that the cache itself is NOT in the address space of its user application (like library or so) to prevent that OutOfMemoryException you mentioned. Everything is fine with your answer here. Please re-read my comment.

Comment: @ultimatecause You're not understanding the use.  You cap the LRU to a set number of items so you don't get the OutOfMemory, and use the LRU to hold the only reference to the images rather than have the bitmap int he model.  That way its in memory, and avoids loading times, but doesn't risk having too many images in memory. And OOM is avoided because a cap is applied to the amount stored. Basically you allow a max number of images (or other resource) in memory on the likelihood they'll be needed again soon.  This is a 50+ year old technique here, you should know about it.

Comment: @ultimatecause In fact this is exactly how processor caches work as well-  they store the previous N requested cache blocks on the theory they'll be needed again soon, and they're dumped on an LRU basis when new ones are needed.  Its how pretty much every caching system works.

Comment: While I completely understand processors & caches, as I have created my own lru cache, just like processor's cache(set associative), I wanted to say that, OutOfMemoryException can actually be avoided in another way as well, when the user application does not has the data in its own space, rather in someone else's space, but still all the data stays in memory. The application holding cache communicates to user application over a socket (I am talking of case when both applications are co-located). This is how redis/memcached etc work. Thanks anyways, lets move on.